# IE8 - jQuery loading issue using javascript call back function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm loading jQuery dynamically using JavaScript. For loading jQuery, callback function is defined and in its call back function call doing some jQuery stuff.

Works great in Firefox, chrome and IE9 as expected but in IE8 gives error message like **"$ is not defined"** mean there is issue with call back function execution in IE8. I have spent a whole day to find out solution but not getting any way.

```
<body>    
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function loadjQuery(callback) {
        var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();

        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        if (ver == 8.0) {
            script.onload = callback.call();
        }
        else {
            script.onload = callback;
        }
        script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js';
        body.appendChild(script);
    }
    loadjQuery(function () {
        alert($(window).height());       
    });

    function getInternetExplorerVersion() {
        var rv = -1;
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent;
            var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
            if (re.exec(ua) != null)
                rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
        }
        return rv;
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

I'm totally stuck. Any help would appreciable?

Comment: Just make sure you have referenced jquery library. Also using IE 8 debugger go to script tab  and verify if you jquery library is appearing and also it should be at top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to code this function as well and the following code seems working perfectly:

```
            // Attach handlers for all browsers
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                    done = true;                        
                    // callback function provided as param
                    if(success != null)
                    {
                        success();
                    }
                    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    //head.removeChild(script);                     
                };              
            };
```